# why 'sed' does not work in this script

Tags: bash, shell-script, centos, sed

I have this script,create_database, that has variables between two patterns:

```
##from script
v1=
v2=
##variables
```

and when i want to delete line between these patterns with `sed` it doesn't work(it's obvious it doesn't works here means it doesn't delete lines and script has the same content after running command):

`sed -i '/##from script/,/##variables/d' /data3/create_database`

i used this command in other scripts and it worked fine but i have no idea why i don't get the same result here. any suggestion?

Comment: this deletes the patterns also, is that what you want to do?

Comment: What result do you get?

Comment: `it doesn't work` is the worst possible problem description. If you take your car to a mechanic and only tell them `it doesn't work` your odds of getting it fixed are slim and the same goes for scripts here or anywhere else. Tell us in what way it doesn't work (wrong output, no output, core dump, error messages, something else?) so we can help you fix it.

Comment: The script looks good. For debugging, it's usually a good idea to test without `-i` option to see whether it is a problem in the script or in file handling.

Answer (score 1):

Could be you are stuck on one of the rare systems where sed does not support the '-i' option.

Try running

```
sed '/##from script/,/##variables/d' /data3/create_database > someotherfile
```

Then check if the file-contents are what they are supposed to.

Did you check the access-rights of the file?

Comment: AFAIR sed -i was not present in old systems, you maybe on the money.